# CoreData relation one-to-one can not display array of Tags belonging to each Listing

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nspredicate

I have two entities Listing and Tags. The relation is working well and saveing to Core Data also.

```swift
class JSONViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var listings: [ListingModel] = []


// saving Json to Core Data...
func saveData(contex: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        
        listings.forEach() { (data) in
               
        let listingFetch: NSFetchRequest<Listing> = Listing.fetchRequest()
          listingFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@",  "\(Int64(data.id))")
               
            do {
             let results:[Listing] = try contex.fetch(listingFetch)
                if results.count == 0 {

                   let entity = Listing(context: contex)
                    entity.id = Int64(data.id)
                    entity.title = data.title
                    entity.name = data.name
                    entity.category = data.category
                    entity.permalink = data.permalink
                    data.tags.forEach { (tagData) in
                        let tags = Tag(context: contex)
                        tags.name = tagData
                        tags.toListing = entity
                    }                 
                    try? contex.save()
                   print ("Inserted Listing")
                }
                else
                {
                   let entity = results[0]
                    entity.id = Int64(data.id)
                    entity.title = data.title
                    entity.name = data.name
                    entity.category = data.category
                    entity.permalink = data.permalink
                    data.tags.forEach { (tagData) in
                        let tag = Tag(context: contex)
                        tag.name = tagData
                        tag.toListing = entity
                    }
                    try? contex.save()
                    print ("Updated Listing: ID: \(entity.id); Title: \(String(describing: entity.title)); Tags: \(String(describing: data.tags))")
                    
                }
                
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("error inserting / updating Listing \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
  
    }
  }
```

Printing after saveing the data is shown bellow.

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnWk8.png)

So eatch Listing have an array of tags.

The problem is when i try to dispay them in the Lisiting detailed view i get an empty view.

I try to sort the tags belonging to the listing like this:

```swift
@FetchRequest(entity: Tag.entity(), sortDescriptors:
    [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Tag.name, ascending: false),],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "toListing == %@" ,  "Listing"))
    var tags : FetchedResults<Tag>
```

And display it in the View like this:

```swift
ForEach(tags){ tag in
   LazyVStack {
      Text(tag.name!)
   }
}
```

Core Data settings are bellow:
[Listing Core Data printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdFju.png)
[Tags Core Data printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7OSe.png)

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "toListing == %@" ,  "listing")`, why ` "listing"` as String, shouldn't it be a `Listing` instance instead?

Comment: "toListing == %@" ,  "Listing" - also not working. Sorry this was the original code actually.

Comment: `toListing` value can't be a String. So it can't be `"Listing"`. That's why you don't find a match.

Comment: ok. Than how can i show the tags foeach listing? i wasthinking to sort toListing for the current Listing or maybe i can pull them directly some how

Comment: I don't do SwiftUI, but when you go from main view to listing detail view, you give your listing detail view a `Listing` instance, no? Use that one in your predicate.

Comment: You don’t need a fetch request for this, the relationship is also an attribute that you can use to access the related entity so you can do something like `let tags = listing.toTag`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 4 Core Data - Fetching Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647282/swift-4-core-data-fetching-relationships). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106990/how-do-i-fetch-a-relationship-of-a-relationship-in-core-data/57107982#57107982

Comment: yes! thank you for that. There is another tini problem

Comment: Any further help is deeply apreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Following [joakim-danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) sugestion i have learned that a related entity becomes a property of that entity.

My code looks like this now:

```swift
      HStack { 
      let tags = Array(arrayLiteral: fetchedData!.toTag!)
                    
                  ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content:      {

                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                       //  ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in // same result
                            
                            ForEach(tags) { tag in
                               LazyHStack {
                                   Text(fetchedData!.toTag!.name!)
                               }
                            }
                        }
                  })
            }
```

Strangely i only get one tag displayed in the view:
[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npriq.png)